# Does Uploadify support jQuery 1.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

Does [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) supports jQuery 1.4?

The site states that it needs:

```
jQuery v1.2.x or greater
```

... but the demo runs on 1.3.2 and I don't feel like trying to get everything to work just to realize that it's some feature I want later is not compatible with my version of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and uploadify 2.1.0 in two pages with no problems, this being copied from the `<head>` of one of those pages (as, you know... proof):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So: yes, it does work fine.

Answer (score 1):

yes 1.4 > 1.2 so it fits in the "greater" condition

Edit:

Don't be afraid if it was designed for 1.2 then it will work, has for what I know, no feature was removed that can affect compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Have you successfully got it to work with 1.4? Usually I'd just go for it but since it'll impact lots of stuff I'm more timid than usual ^^

Answer (score 1):

It should work with 1.4.

And if it doesn't you can still download jQuery's official Backwards compatibility for jQuery 1.3: http://github.com/jquery/jquery-compat-1.3

Answer (score 1):

I use it with 1.4.2